# how to put 2 div tag on 1 line and bullet does not follow

Tags: html, css, css-float, inline-styles, bullet

I've learning HTML/CSS for 1-2 weeks and currently on a assignment that requires putting 2 div tag on 1 single line and bulleting that line. This assignment does not require float, flex or grid, just using

```
display: inline-block
```

I tried and managed to put 2 div in a line but when the content in div2 is more than 1 line, div1 is kinda shorter than div2 (see image [output](https://imgur.com/a/3X2emYV), I also tried putting `vertical-align: top` into div1 but then the bullet does not follow. Here a sample test:

```css
.div1,
.div2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  /* height: 100px; */
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.div2 {
  width: 500px;
  /* height: 100px; */
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="div1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And finally, should I put the entire parent div (.container) in a li tag (line3), or as the following ul > .container > li > div1 div2? First Stackoverflow post ever, so apologize for any inconveniences! Thanks.

Here is an expected result (see image [expectation](https://imgur.com/a/6zUyrEM))

Comment: What is the framework you using. bootstrap or ?? you can use bootstrap to solve this issue using grid system

Comment: It's not clear what you want to see. But you certainly don't need the `.container` div, as the `li` is a container. Do you *have* to use a list? Was that part of the exercise?

Comment: @ralph.m here is an sample of layout [image](https://imgur.com/a/KowDWzz), so it has to be a list, right?

Comment: @nuke_infer I just started this course, so no framework yet, just pure HTML and CSS

Comment: It doesn't have to be a list, unless that's part of the exercise. Have you been told not to use Flex or Grid? Because they would make this much easier — especially if you need those equal-height columns.

Comment: Your image doesn't show bullets, though, so still a bit confused about what you want.

Comment: @ralph.m later in this exercise I have to make a timeline list, so should be a list, and the float/flex/grid course is right after this assignment, so I wanna understand the basic before going into any advanced layout

Comment: Okay, but to clarify: you don't need the bullet, and you don't need those background colors, or do you? (It's a little harder if you do need the colors.)

Comment: @ralph.m yes, those background color is just to visualize, and i need bullet for the final timeline list, like [this](https://imgur.com/a/FTVbg7t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this?

```css
.div1,
.div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ul {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div1 {
  width: 200px;
}
.div2 {
  width: 500px;
}
p {margin: 0;}
ul::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1000px;
  top: 0;
  left: 27px;
  background: #d7d7d7;
}

li + li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="div1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <div class="div1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Exactly like this, there is also some property I dont know yet maybe I'll look them up later. Thanks for your help